# how to join parse() results in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Say there is a product with the follow json structure, ie a product with multiple links to be crawled.

```
[
  {
    "id": "888",
    "suppliers": {
      "shop1": {
        "url": "http://www.example1.com./item1",
        "price": "19.99",
      },
      "shop2": {
        "url": "http://www.example2.com./item2",
        "price": "29.95",
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I am using Scrapy to crawl the two websites and update the prices.
Everything is working fine except Scrapy returned two results separately.

How can I "combine" the results of from the two links? i.e. forming a single object like the above json structure in one line?

Here is an existing snippet I am using. Any helps will be appreciated.

```
class ProductSpider(Spider):
    name = "productspider"
    allowed_domains = ['example1.com', 'example2.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example1.com./item1', 'http://www.example2.com./item2']

    def parse(self, response):    
        item = ProductItem()
        item['id'] = '888'
        item['suppliers'] = {'shop1':'', 'shop2':''}

        if (response.meta['download_slot'] == 'www.example1.com'):
            parse_example1_page() # and assign it to item shop1

        if (response.meta['download_slot'] == 'www.example2.com'):
            parse_example2_page() # and assign it to item shop2

        yield item
```

Comment: Is it only two urls you need to visit to form an item, or you need to scale it infinitely? Thanks.

Comment: I used two urls just for simplicity, it maybe up to 10 or any other numbers

Comment: Okay, and you know all of the URLs beforehand and they are kept inside `start_urls`, right? Thanks.

Comment: all urls are fetched from a file

Comment: the second `if` can be an `elif ` `response.meta['download_slot'] ` cannot be equal to two urls at the same time

Comment: Is it true that every URL has it's own corresponding parse function in your case?

Comment: every website has its own structure for the same product, so I guess it needs different xpath?

Answer (score 1):

Your desired output is a re-organization of the data that you scrape. Trying to combine the extraction and the processing part will be brittle and probably hard to understand. The data as-fetched may even be useful in its original form (you could combine different crawls, perform different processing, etc). Consider splitting the task into two parts: crawling to fetch the data, and processing to reformat it. You've already got the scraping part, here's an example of post-processing. I used a simple one-record-per-line json format, which has the advantage of not needing to load the entire (raw) data set in memory. You can use whatever intermediate storage you prefer.

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict

# the (fake) fetching
scrapy_data = [ {"id":"888", "url":"blah.com/888", "shop":"shop1", "price": 99.2 },
{"id":"3", "url":"blah.com/3", "shop":"shop1", "price": 33.1 },
{"id":"888", "url":"foo.com/888", "shop":"shop2", "price": 423.0 },
{"id":"42", "url":"foo.com/42", "shop":"shop2", "price": 1.20 }, ]

with open('records.json','w') as fh:
    # pretend the data items are coming from scrapy
    for item in scrapy_data:
        json.dump(item, fh)
        fh.write("\n")


# the (real) processing
products = defaultdict(dict)

with open('records.json') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        item = json.loads(line)
        pid, url, shop, price = item["id"], item["url"], item["shop"], item["price"]
        products[pid][shop] = {"url": url, "price":price}

collated = [ { "id": key, "suppliers":val } for key, val in products.iteritems() ]

print(json.dumps(collated, sort_keys=True, indent=2))
```

The output looks like:

```
[
  {
    "id": "3", 
    "suppliers": {
      "shop1": {
        "price": 33.1, 
        "url": "blah.com/3"
      }
    }
  }, 
  {
    "id": "888", 
    "suppliers": {
      "shop1": {
        "price": 99.2, 
        "url": "blah.com/888"
      }, 
      "shop2": {
        "price": 423.0, 
        "url": "foo.com/888"
      }
    }
  }, 
  {
    "id": "42", 
    "suppliers": {
      "shop2": {
        "price": 1.2, 
        "url": "foo.com/42"
      }
    }
  }
]
```